# Angular: NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken config

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, angular-providers

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken config]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken config]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken config!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken config]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[InjectionToken config]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken config!
```

My module file already has `import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';` and has `InjectionToken` in the providers list. What could be causing this error? Does InjectionToken  rely on some other provider? This error message seems pretty useless.

Comment: Post your module code where you're including firebase, versions, etc.

Comment: you probably didn't import some module, pretty sure you dont need InjectionToken in providers, this error is generic. pls post app.module.ts code